# how to concat string to array element in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an array as

```
["first_name"]
```

and I want to convert it to

```
["user.first_name"]
```

I cannot figure out how I can do this in rails.

Comment: `arr[0] = "user.#{arr[0]}"` or `arr[0].prepend('user.')` or `arr[0].insert(0,'user.')` or ...?

Comment: @engineersmnky I tried this but then it is no more an array: 
"user.email" ..This is what it returned

Comment: `arr = ["first_name"]; arr[0].prepend('user.'); arr #=> ["user.first_name"]` <- updates the string inside the array. You you have to do this a bunch of times then `arr.map(&'user.'.method(:+))` would work too and will return a new array

Comment: @engineersmnky your first comment way right, you want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to append text to the values you have in a array you're going to probably want to loop through the data and append to each element in the array like so:

```
my_array = ["test", "test2", "first_name"]
new_array = my_array.collect{|value| "user.#{value}" }
```

new_array will now be:

`["user.test", "user.test2", "user.first_name"]`

You could also just overwrite your original array by using collect! like so

```
my_array = ["test", "test2", "first_name"]
my_array.collect!{|value| "user.#{value}" }
```

This will of course overwrite your original original data in my_array

If you would like to just change one value in the array you could use the index of that array and assign the value

```
my_array = ["test", "test2", "first_name"]
my_array[1] = "user.#{my_array[1]}}
```

my_array will now read:

`["test", "user.test2", "first_name"]`

Ruby doc info: https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Array.html#method-i-collect

`collect` and `map` are alias for each other fyi.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you've multiple elements in your array, I recommend using [`.map`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map).

It allows you to iterate the array elements, and return a new value for each of them.

```rb
%w[first_name last_name email].map do |attr|
  "user.#{attr}"
end
# => [user.first_name, user.last_name, user.email]
```